# order of updating columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

```
Update tmp
SET BakColumn1 = Column1
,Column1 = Column1 + ' Changed Value'
```

Is there any guarantee that I will always get the Column1 original content in the Backup column (BakColumn) if my statement is like above in MS-SQL 2008 or higher versions? If not is there any other way of doing it or do I have to execute 2 separate transactions?

Can higher than 1 Degree Of Parallelism (MAX-DOP) cause issues?

Comment: Whatever happens when you test it, is probably what will happen every time.

Comment: @TabAlleman I suspect DoP has a role to play here and that's why want to make sure if anyone has tried this or has a concrete answer

Comment: My understanding is that the update will be treated as an atomic operation and the locking mechanism will guarantee that correct values are used at all times. The degree of parallelism should not matter due to the atomic nature of the update. I haven't found any good reference yet though so I might be wrong on this.

Comment: Parallelism does not split up operations on the same row. That is not at all how parallelism works. It splits up the rows into threads but each thread will handle 1 entire row. This article is a MUST read for anybody with questions about parallelism. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-and-using-parallelism-in-sql-server/

Comment: I think this has some bearing on the question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34091/23463

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a guarantee that you will always get the Column1 original content in the Backup column.

Order does not matter.

For this you can check out swapping values between columns and verify the result.

```
Update tmp
SET BakColumn1 = Column1
,Column1 =BakColumn1
```

I think, the key here is original value of the row is maintained temporarily and referred to throughout .

Parallelism is merely intended for performance boost and does not alter functional behavior. If you see any discrepancy using DOP then you can report a bug -:)

Hope this helps.